# Comment répond-on au téléphone en français ?

Tags: expressions, usage, conventions, téléphone

Dans les cours que je fais en ce moment, ils disent que les français se répondent au téléphone avec « à l'appareil ».

Mais je pense que la majorité dit simplement « allô ». Est-ce vrai ?

Comment se répondent les français au téléphone à la maison et au travail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## À la maison :

> - Allô?
> - Bonjour?
> - Oui allô?
> - Oui bonjour?
> - [Nom] à l'appareil.
> - Oui bonjour, qui est à l'appareil ?

Elles sont toutes des façons familières de répondre au téléphone.

(Au Québec, "*Oui bonjour?*" est le plus utilisé)

## Au travail (Nom et compagnie fictifs):

> - [Martin] bonjour, comment puis-je vous aider?
> - [Société Immobilier Plus] bonjour, [Martin] à l'appareil !

Des phrases similaires à cette dernière sont la norme.

Comment: Et simplement "à l'appareil" n'utilise plus? Il a été utilisé dans le passé?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûre qu'en France on utilise encore beaucoup « à l'appareil », que ce soit pour se présenter ou pour demander qui est au bout du fil.

Comment: « comment puis-je vous aider? » est peut-être beaucoup moins utilisé en France (un de ces anglicismes..), on commence à l'entendre dans les magasins, au téléphone je n'ai pas l'impression que ce soit répandu.

Comment: @AndreaCarrer *"À l'appareil"* n'est jamais utilisé ici. Je n'ai jamais entendu cela. (Merci pour les corrections Laure)

Comment: @Laure, qu'utilisez-vous en France pour répondre au téléphone au travaille? *"[Nom entreprise] bonjour."*? Nous utilisons aussi cela, je dirais que c'est autant répandu, cela dépend de l'entreprise.

Comment: Moi je dis juste « Allô ? oui ? » chez moi sur le fixe, et au bureau : « [Nom de la société] bonjour ». Les coutumes chez soi sont certainement diverses, et en pleine évolution car les téléphones portables, et les fixes de plus en plus, présentent le nom de l’appelant, et dans ce cas là on dit directement « bonjour machin ».

Comment: Chez les militaires, ceux qui disent _affirmatif_ au lieu de _oui_, on ne dit pas _qui est à l'appareil_, on dit _à qui ai-je l'honneur_.

Answer (score 2):

En France pour un appel personnel on entend en général

> Allô ? ou *Tartanpion* ? ou Allô *Tartanpion* ? ou Bonjour/Salut/Coucou *Tartanpion* !

sans ordre particulier. Celui qui appelle ou celui qui est appelé (lorsqu'il connait son interlocuteur) parlent parfois simultanément. S'ensuivent généralement les salutations habituelles (*Hey !*, *Comment ça va ?*, *Tu vas bien ?*, etc.)

Si la personne au bout du fil n'est pas celle qu'on espérait elle peut par exemple répondre :

> Ah non, c'est *M<sup>me</sup> Michoux* à l'appareil. Attendez, je vous le passe.

Dans ce cas « à l'appareil » est facultatif, on ne l'entend plus très souvent de nos jours. Lorsqu'on ne sait pas qui appelle, il arrive tout de même qu'on pose la question « Qui est à l'appareil ? » ou « À qui ai-je affaire ? »

Pour un appel professionnel, le service ou la société, etc. qui répond se présente en général en premier. Quelques exemples possibles d'introduction.

> Bonjour. Secrétariat de l'association *Profitez-du-bon-air*, que puis-je faire pour vous ?
>
> Restaurant *Chez-Gaston*, bonjour.
>
> Allô, service après vente *CtoutKC*, à votre service.
>
> Cabinet dentaire de *Trou-paumé-sous-bois*, *Docteur Martin* au téléphone, j'écoute.

etc., etc.

Lorsqu'un professionnel appelle un particulier, ce dernier émet en général un simple « Allô » ou « Oui allô ? » et celui qui appelle se présente en premier :

> Bonjour, ici *Catherine Blanc*, votre conseillère à la banque *On-veut-des-sousous*, je vous appelle à propos de…
>
> Bonjour, *Robert Cépasmonvrainom* pour la Société *Vive-l'Arnaque*, vous connaissez peut-être … ? Non ? Alors, laissez-moi vous expliquer…

Answer (score 2):

En Suisse romande (francophone), on répond parfois “à l'Allemande”, en donnant simplement son nom de famille, sans “bonjour” ni question.

> Chapuis!

Je ne pense pas qu'on dise jamais “à l'appareil” sans dire un nom avant (“untel à l'appareil”).

Answer (score 1):

Pour la maison, le plus commun, c'est "Allo". On donne de moins en moins son nom par question de sécurité.

Au travail, allo est assez informel, on utilise plutot "nom de l'entreprise, bonjour", cela depend a quel poste vous etes !

Comment: Par question de sécurité ?? Je dirais plutôt que c'est parce qu'on sait qui on appelle.

Comment: Ce que j entends par la, c'est qu'il n'est pas judicieux de donner des informations personnelles ( comme son nom ), elles peuvent mettre mal utilisées ( extorsions ).

Comment: Arrive-t-il souvent qu'une personne qui t'appelle ne sait pas qui tu es?

Comment: Sur un telephone fixe que partage une famille, tu ne sais jamais qui tu as au bout du fil, le fils, la mere, l'amant, etc...

Comment: Qu'amènerait de plus à celui qui appelle de savoir qu'une femme partageant le logis de "M. [Nom]" s'appelle "Marie"? En fait, ce serait justement une raison de **dire** son nom en répondant pour clarifier celui qui est à l'appareil. (Beaucoup de monde croyait avoir à faire à mon père quand moi ou mon frère répondait au téléphone)

Comment: @Sifu On peut toujours demander, bien sûr… De toutes façons, si la conversation continue, on révèle bien quelquechose donc aucune de ces considérations n'est vraiment déterminante dans un sens ou dans l'autre. La seule raison de ne pas donner son nom d'emblée est de forcer l'appelant à commencer.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro En tout état de cause, je ne pense pas que cette histoire de “sécurité” soit vraiment déterminante, en France.